# SQLite 3 & Electron 1.4 on Mac OSX

Tags: node.js, macos, sqlite, electron

I've been developing my own electron app without any problem. I've used SQLite3 to stock some data for my app.

But the problem is, that when i build my app, the application can't load the database.

How am i supposed to get SQLite3 working outside of the dev environment?

Here is my build command: `electron-packager . WhatsNext --out=./dist --overwrite --asar --icon=WhatNext256.icns --all`

EDIT: my workaround is down below :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, using SQJ.js is an easier option with Electron.
So...

Good luck :)